# ViewState Encryption in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, encryption, viewstate

Why is it that I see the same hash value generated when I use different algorithms for viewstate encryption. 
I have added below lines to the web.config file

pages viewstateEncryptionMode="Always" enableViewStateMac="true".../>

machineKey validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" validation="AES" decryption="Auto" />

Also, compilation debug="false" ... > is set.

No matter what I use (AES, MD5, SHA1, 3DES), it generates the same hash. Is there something I am missing out.

Please let me know.

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article on [Encrypting Viewstate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479501.aspx). It's for ASP.Net 2.0. which should be fine for 3.5.

Comment: Thanks. But this link only talk about encrypting the viewstate. My question is about making different algorithms to work with the viewstate encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Via [P&P on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx#paght000007_webfarmdeploymentconsiderations):

> Forms authentication defaults to SHA1
>   for tamper proofing (if  or
>   ,
>   then forms authentication hashes the
>   forms authentication ticket by using
>   either MD5 or HMACSHA1 **(HMACSHA1 is
>   used even if validation is set to AES
>   or 3DES).** Forms authentication then
>   encrypts the ticket using the
>   algorithm specified in the decryption
>   attribute. (The decryption attribute
>   was introduced in ASP.NET 2.0.)

Therefore, theoretically, only SHA1 and MD5 should differ in the hash that is produced.